# Convert Map<String, String> to List of POJO - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Tags: java, gson

Currently, I plan to convert the following `Map<String, String>` to `List` of POJO.

```
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put("stock_price_alerts", "[{\"code\":\"KO\",\"rise_above\":7.0,\"size\":1000.89,\"price\":10,\"time\":1519625135173,\"fall_below\":null},{\"code\":\"BRK-B\",\"rise_above\":180,\"size\":100,\"price\":190,\"time\":1519160399911,\"fall_below\":null}]");
System.out.println(m);
```

When we print out the `Map` at console, it looks like

```
{stock_price_alerts=[{"code":"KO","rise_above":7.0,"size":1000.89,"price":10,"time":1519625135173,"fall_below":null},{"code":"BRK-B","rise_above":180,"size":100,"price":190,"time":1519160399911,"fall_below":null}]}
```

I prepare 2 POJO classes.

### StockPriceAlert.java

```
package sandbox;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class StockPriceAlert {

    @SerializedName("code")
    @Expose
    public String code;
    @SerializedName("fall_below")
    @Expose
    public Object fallBelow;
    @SerializedName("rise_above")
    @Expose
    public long riseAbove;
    @SerializedName("price")
    @Expose
    public long price;
    @SerializedName("time")
    @Expose
    public long time;
    @SerializedName("size")
    @Expose
    public long size;

    /**
    * No args constructor for use in serialization
    * 
    */
    public StockPriceAlert() {
    }

    /**
    * 
    * @param fallBelow
    * @param time
    * @param price
    * @param riseAbove
    * @param code
    * @param size
    */
    public StockPriceAlert(String code, Object fallBelow, long riseAbove, long price, long time, long size) {
        super();
        this.code = code;
        this.fallBelow = fallBelow;
        this.riseAbove = riseAbove;
        this.price = price;
        this.time = time;
        this.size = size;
    }

}
```

### StockPriceAlertResponse.java

```
package sandbox;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class StockPriceAlertResponse {

    @SerializedName("stock_price_alerts")
    @Expose
    private List<StockPriceAlert> stockPriceAlerts = null;

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public StockPriceAlertResponse() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param stockPriceAlerts
     */
    public StockPriceAlertResponse(List<StockPriceAlert> stockPriceAlerts) {
        super();
        this.stockPriceAlerts = stockPriceAlerts;
    }

    public List<StockPriceAlert> getStockPriceAlerts() {
        return stockPriceAlerts;
    }

    public void setStockPriceAlerts(List<StockPriceAlert> stockPriceAlerts) {
        this.stockPriceAlerts = stockPriceAlerts;
    }

}
```

---

I wrote the following code to perform conversion.

```
package sandbox;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 *
 * @author yccheok
 */
public class Main {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>();
        m.put("stock_price_alerts", "[{\"code\":\"KO\",\"rise_above\":7.0,\"size\":1000.89,\"price\":10,\"time\":1519625135173,\"fall_below\":null},{\"code\":\"BRK-B\",\"rise_above\":180,\"size\":100,\"price\":190,\"time\":1519160399911,\"fall_below\":null}]");

        System.out.println(m);

        final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        JsonElement jsonElement = gson.toJsonTree(m);
        StockPriceAlertResponse stockPriceAlertResponse = gson.fromJson(jsonElement, StockPriceAlertResponse.class);
        List<StockPriceAlert> stockPriceAlerts = stockPriceAlertResponse.getStockPriceAlerts();
    }
}
```

However, I get the following Exception

> Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING

Any idea how I can resolve this?

*Note, `Map<String, String> m` is output from 3rd party library. So, that input is out of my control.*

Comment: Every map value has to be converted separately with your approach.

Comment: @JoopEggen Sorry. I don't understand. Can you kindly explain more?

Comment: I have added an answer. Though @pirho also has a similar answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the original map's values will stay a String.

```
    String mJsonString = m.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> String.format("\"%s\":%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(",", "{", "}"));

    System.out.println(mJsonString);

    final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
    StockPriceAlertResponse stockPriceAlertResponse = gson.fromJson(mJsonString,
            StockPriceAlertResponse.class);
    List<StockPriceAlert> stockPriceAlerts = stockPriceAlertResponse.getStockPriceAlerts();
```

In the data is an error, for size: a floating point value that should have been integer.

Answer (score 2):

Do simply:

```
StockPriceAlertResponse res = gson.fromJson(""+m, StockPriceAlertResponse.class);
```

When `m.toString()` is called it generates something starting like:

```
{ stock_price_alerts= ...
```

but `Gson` seems to handle `=` even it should be `:`.

**Note**: you need to change

```
public long size;
```

to:

```
public float size;
```

because of values like:

```
"size": 1000.89
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you convert something that already is `JSON` into `JSON` again by calling `toJsonTree`. When you then call `fromJson` on the result it will convert it back to what you originally gave it: A `Map<String, String>`.

You have to call `fromJson` directly on the values in your map. Since the value you have is an array for whatever reason (enclosed by `[` and `]`), you have to first use `fromJson` with `JsonArray.class`, and then `fromJson` on the first element in the resulting array with your `StockPriceAlert.class`:

```
    for (String value : m.values())
    {
        StockPriceAlert stockPriceAlert = gson.fromJson(gson.fromJson(value, JsonArray.class).get(0), StockPriceAlert.class);
    }
```